# Neatly Inset Octagon in Parent Octagon

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am attempting to inset an octagon with text in another octagon to simulate a border. However, as you can see from my code, the odd white corners of the smaller octagon are ruining things. Also, if I set the corners to have the same color as the larger octagon, I cannot have a thin border, which is my preference.

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
}
#octagon {
  width: 558px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 260px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#octagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 29px solid red;
  border-left: 29px solid white;
  border-right: 29px solid white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 0;
}
#octagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 29px solid red;
  border-left: 29px solid white;
  border-right: 29px solid white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 0;
}
#octagon p {
  padding: 50px;
}
#octagonTwo {
  height: 264px;
  width: 578px;
  background: aquamarine;
  position: relative;
}
#octagonTwo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 29px solid aquamarine;
  border-left: 29px solid white;
  border-right: 29px solid white;
  width: 520px;
  height: 0;
}
#octagonTwo:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 29px solid aquamarine;
  border-left: 29px solid white;
  border-right: 29px solid white;
  width: 520px;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="octagon">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>

<div id="octagonTwo"></div>
```

Comment: The modern way is to use SVG...complex CSS shapes are overly complex and non-performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have  a great padding in the inner **p**, we can use that and go for transparent corners :

(several dimensions need to be adjusted)

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
}
#octagon {
  width: 558px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#octagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 29px solid red;
  border-left: 29px solid transparent;
  border-right: 29px solid transparent;
  width: 500px;
  height: 0;
}
#octagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 29px solid red;
  border-left: 29px solid transparent;
  border-right: 29px solid transparent;
  width: 500px;
  height: 0;
}
#octagon p {
  padding: 21px 50px;
  margin-top: 46px;

}
#octagonTwo {
  height: 206px;
  width: 578px;
  background: aquamarine;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
}
#octagonTwo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 25px solid aquamarine;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  width: 528px;
  height: 0;
}
#octagonTwo:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid aquamarine;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  width: 528px;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="octagon">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>

<div id="octagonTwo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what exactly you are asking for. But if you want a hexagonal border and remove those white corners, here you are :-

```css
        body {
            background-color: purple;
        }

#octagon {
width:558px;
background: red;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 260px;
z-index: 1;
}

#octagon:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border-bottom: 29px solid red;
border-left: 29px solid aquamarine;
border-right: 29px solid aquamarine;
width: 500px;
height: 0;
}

#octagon:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
border-top: 29px solid red;
border-left: 29px solid aquamarine;
border-right: 29px solid aquamarine;
width: 500px;
height: 0;
}

        #octagon p {
            padding: 50px; 
        }

         #octagonTwo {
height: 264px;
width:578px;
background: aquamarine;
position: relative;
}

#octagonTwo:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border-bottom: 29px solid aquamarine;
border-left: 29px solid purple;
border-right: 29px solid purple;
width: 520px;
height: 0;
}

#octagonTwo:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
border-top: 29px solid aquamarine;
border-left: 29px solid purple;
border-right: 29px solid purple;
width: 520px;
height: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Octagon</title>

    
</head>

<body>

    <div id="octagon"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p></div>
<div id="octagonTwo"></div>

    <script>


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

If it is not what you want, let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much! But, as I noted above, the borders must be rather thick using this method. Also, you can see the corners of the smaller "div."

Comment: yes. Now I understood what you want ! Can you specify height of first octagon.

Comment: Yes! 226px is the height.

Comment: I tried my best. It is not possible using css. If we try to thin the border, the corners of first  div always cut the second div. Maybe its possible using SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I see this a lille late, but , again, gradients can be used for this :

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  color:white;
  text-shadow:0 0 1px black;
  text-align:justify;
  margin:1em 0;
  padding: 2em;
  width:40%;
  background:/* draw the borders by bits to overlap them */
    linear-gradient(to top, transparent 3em, turquoise 3em) bottom right,
    linear-gradient(to top, transparent 3em, turquoise 3em) bottom left,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 3em, turquoise 3em) top right,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 3em, turquoise 3em) top left,
    linear-gradient(to left, transparent 3em, turquoise 3em )  top right,
    linear-gradient(to left, transparent 3em, turquoise 3em ) bottom right,
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 3em, turquoise 3em )  top left,
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 3em, turquoise 3em ) bottom left,
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 2em, turquoise 2em, turquoise 2.5em, tomato 2.5em, gray) bottom left,
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 2em, turquoise 2em, turquoise 2.5em, tomato 2.5em, gray) bottom right,
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 2em, turquoise 2em, turquoise 2.5em, tomato 2.5em, gray ) top left,
    linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 2em, turquoise 2em, turquoise 2.5em, tomato 2.5em, gray) top right
    ;
  /* size those bits */
  background-size:
    0.5em 50%, 
    0.5em 50%,
    0.5em 50%,
    0.5em 50%, 
    50% 0.5em, 
    50% 0.5em, 
    50% 0.5em, 
    50% 0.5em, 
    50% 50%, 
    50% 50%, 
    50% 50%, 
    50% 50%  ;
  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  vertical-align:top;
}
p {
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</p>
</div>
```

[codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pyOeWw)